# VBA Multiple Filters applied via user Input

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to create a macro with the data set below, where a user can enter the number of the countries they want to filter and then enters the name of the countries to filter from the list.

[image: [Dataset]

I need the macro to allow me to apply multiple filters (depending on the number of countries). So far, I have managed to write a code which allows me to enter all the input details for as many countries as I want, but only displays one country being filtered which can be seen below.

[image: My Attempted Result]

But If i enter 2 countries, I would like the macro to ideally spit out the below result,

[image: Ideal Result]

The macro code I used can also be found here,

```
Sub autofilter()

Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim irow As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim userinput(51) As Variant
'Dim userinput As Variant
Dim userinput2 As Variant
Dim storage As Variant

Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Countries")

LastRow = wsCopyTo.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

userinput2 = InputBox("How many Countries do you want to include?")
If StrPtr(userinput2) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
End If
For k = 1 To userinput2
    userinput(k) = InputBox("What Countries to include?")
    If StrPtr(userinput(k)) = 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next k
i = 0
For ik = 1 To userinput2
    wsCopyTo.Range("$C$3:$C$" & LastRow).autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("*" & userinput(ik) & "*", " "), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Next ik
End Sub
```

Comment: when posting code and sample data, please post it _as text_, so we can copy / paste it for testing. If you feel an image adds additional value, post that too, but always post as test first.

Comment: Sorry! I have edited the post now.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it, but don't forget the _data_

Comment: I am not sure how to upload the data

Comment: You are only getting one country in the filter because you're only setting one country to the filter.  Yes, you're using an array.  Yes, you need to use an array. But you do not need that `For ik` loop, and that is what is causing your problem   It's looping through your array and setting one element at a time.  The next iteration come along and replaces the filter with a new country.

Comment: I want to have multiple filters depending on the user input. When i remove the for loop, it only allows me to have a one filter at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

removing the `For ik` loop

And replacing `[...]Criteria:=Array("*" & userinput(ik) & "*", " "), [...]`

with `[...]Criteria1:=userinput, [...]`

Comment: It works, but only allows for one filter. I want to have multiple filters if possible depending on user input.